# Why do I need to cast the result of myCollection.toArray(new String[0])

Tags: java, generics

The `Collection#toArray(T[])` signature is the following

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

Most of the time, I write this code and **everything works** :

```
Collection<String> myCollection = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
String[] myArray = myCollection.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Today, I can't get my "usual" `Collection<String>` for some reasons, and then I came up with :

```
Collection myCollection = someNonGenericResult();
String[] myArray = myCollection.toArray(new String[0]);
```

And in this case, I get this compilation error :

> incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]

I know that I can cast the result of `myCollection.toArray(new String[0])`, but I would like to know why. I believed the method genericity could avoid that.

Comment: because a generic Collection might not include only strings.

Comment: [See the section titled *A raw type is the erasure of that type*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/2891664)

Comment: the SO community is really impressive ...